# How to easily test and debug chaincode without having blockchain network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger fabric, is there any easy way to test and debug chaincode directly from eclipse\Visual studio code without deploying it to a blockchain network? like simulator.
something like hyperledger composer playground where you test the smart contract directly without any network, it will make the fabric development process easier and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I recently found an answer to my question, by using MockStub for fabric unit testing.
From the package `"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"` you can use `shim.NewMockStub` to create smart contract and test your procedures with debugging feature, and even without having any blockchain network.

Here is full [Example](https://github.com/shiki-tak/Chaincode_for_Go_developers) on how to use Mock stub to test your chaincode